# Converting 'touchstart' event to 'mousedown' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got one request from my client to change the HTML package to support Desktop browsers. Initially that package was developed to support only the ipads. So the package was developed with full of 'touchstart' event. now I want to convert the `touchstart` into `mousedown` or `touchstart mousedown`. sample code for your reference. This is working fine in iPads. But not in desktop.

```
 $('.toggle-button').bind("touchstart",function() {
   alert("toggle button tapped");
 });
```

I am sure find and replace will take more time and not the effective one. Is there any solution for this or find and replace is the only solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

trigger the mousedown event ,inside touchstart event.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('yourdiv');
 $('body').on('touchstart', '[id^="showmenu_"]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'))
    });
$(elem).on('mousedown', function () {
    alert('on');
});
```